# What wrong, fullcalendar JSON feed not showing while use eventSources

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, fullcalendar, codeigniter-3

Like everyone else I also have problem when displaying event in fullcalendar.
Below is my controller for JSON data:

```
function schedule($id) {
    $data = $this->M_care->getSchedule($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

This controller produce JSON data like that:

```
[{"id":"51","title":"test date","start":"2022-03-31T00:00:00-05:00","end":"2022-03-31T00:00:00-05:00"},{"id":"53","title":"test date","start":"2022-03-29T00:00:00-05:00","end":"2022-03-29T00:00:00-05:00"}]
```

and below is script for render calendar:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
    var initialLocaleCode = 'id';
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var url = '<?= base_url('service/Care/schedule/').$id; ?>';
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      validRange: function(nowDate) {
      return {
        start: nowDate
        };
      },
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: url, 
          color: 'red',
          textColor: 'black',
          display: 'background'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

The `$id` in the url variable get from `$id = $this->session->userdata('event');`
Above code is not working for displaying events data. I have trying to solve this for several days, and search related question but none of them fix this issue.

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with your events feed - assuming the JSON is produced exactly as you've shown, then the events show up exactly as you should expect them to in fullCalendar. Here's a demo of the exact same code, just using a static JSON data source in the URL instead of your controller (but it returns the same JSON that you've provided in your question): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYeoJdP

Comment: Please note that, in the demo, you must open the "week" view and navigate to the week which contains your events, in order to see them. They do not show up in the "month" view because they are timed events (not all-day events) and they are "background" events. This is expected, and is mentioned in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events where it says _"Background events that are timed will only be rendered on the time slots in TimeGrid view. Background events that are all-day will only be rendered in month view or the all-day slots of TimeGrid view."_

Comment: I strongly suspect that your problem is actually that you haven't understood (or just haven't read) the documentation and are expecting these events to show up in the Month view, but this will not happen.

Comment: any idea for convert all events become all day events?